# Remove Query String from Google jQuery

Tags: google

Was wondering if anyone knew of a way to remove the query string from external Javascript sources, such as Google's jQuery.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter `'script_loader_src'`, you get the source URL as first argument. Then run `remove_query_arg()` on this URL and return the shortened version.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_script_version_parameter' );

function remove_script_version_parameter( $src )
{
    return remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but sounds like a solution. My thing is, I use CloudFlare, and I'm trying to remove the query code from their JS. Not really something im enqueueing or anything

Comment: See my update. It work with enqueued scripts only. Hard coded scripts should never be used, because there is no API for these.